# Eclipse JUnit: Not passing or failing my tests?

Tags: eclipse, junit

What does the blue triangle mean? What are the icons with no mark at all on them?

It seems that if I run the tests individually, they all pass 1/1.

[image]

Comment: simply points that the current test is running. the test under the blue triangle without marks are waiting for to be executed. If the blue triangle hangs on one test for a lot of time probably you've a problem there because the test it's not ending.

Answer (score 4):

This means your test is hanging - starts and never exits. Run with debugger and use the "pause" button to interrupt and see what it's doing.